# How to connect UL > LI list items in angular (without jquery)

Tags: html, css

I have elements in the `li` list and I want to connect them using a simple line so that it looks like a pipeline.

I want to implement pipeline like structure to these elements

[image]

The HTML I have prepared

```
<ul>
    <li class="pipeline-box">New</li> ---
    <li class="pipeline-box">Order Placed</li> ---
    <li class="pipeline-box">Order confirmed</li>---
    <li class="pipeline-box">In Process</li>---
    <li class="pipeline-box">Ready For Dispatch</li>---
    <li class="pipeline-box">On the Way</li>---
    <li class="pipeline-box">Delivered</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS for pipeline-box

```
.pipeline-box {
      border: 1px solid #696666;
      width: fit-content;
      padding: 6px;
      background: #cccec9;
      border-radius: 50px;
      font-family: "avenir Medium";
      font-size: 0.8rem !important;
    }
```

I want it like this

[image]

Comment: You can purely implement this with CSS, with the help of ::before/::after

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far? What (if anything) prevents you to do that in pure css like Sonia said ?

Comment: Use CSS for it. Hint: `:before`  `:after` element will act as a line, between blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really using the ul/li feature so I'd suggest

```css
   .pipeline-box {
      border: 1px solid #696666;
      width: fit-content;
      padding: 6px;
      background: #cccec9;
      border-radius: 50px;
      font-family: "avenir Medium";
      font-size: 0.8rem !important;
    }
    
 .list {
     flex-direction: row;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: flex;
     place-content: center space-around;
     align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="pipeline-box">New</div> ---
    <div class="pipeline-box">Order Placed</div> ---
    <div class="pipeline-box">Order confirmed</div>---
    <div class="pipeline-box">In Process</div>---
    <div class="pipeline-box">Ready For Dispatch</div>---
    <div class="pipeline-box">On the Way</div>---
    <div class="pipeline-box">Delivered</div>
</div>
```

Sidenote: using `!important` is usually viewed as bad practice, avoid it if you can

Answer (score 0):

Just use the CSS pseudo-element `:after`. The `---` connectors are just presentation elements, not part of your content and as such would be better separated from the code structure.

In the example below I used `:last-child` to remove the extra connector in the last element.

```css
.pipeline-box {
  display: inline-block;
}
.pipeline-box::after {
  content: "---";
}

.pipeline-box:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="pipeline-box">New</li>
    <li class="pipeline-box">Order Placed</li>
    <li class="pipeline-box">Order confirmed</li>
    <li class="pipeline-box">In Process</li>
    <li class="pipeline-box">Ready For Dispatch</li>
    <li class="pipeline-box">On the Way</li>
    <li class="pipeline-box">Delivered</li>
</ul>
```

And by the way you don't necessarily need the "pipeline-box" class on every element (specially if all elements have the same class, there's no point), you could use the class already on the `ul` and target your objects using `.list li`, assuming all `li` elements in your list will be connected. Or add the `pipeline-box` class to the `ul` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Added a `span` inside `li` which will contain the text and will be shown as bubble and then I made that link using the `::before` of `li`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pipeline-box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}
.pipeline-box::before {
  background: #c5c5c5;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  left: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.pipeline-box>span {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "avenir Medium";
  font-size: 0.8em !important;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.pipeline-box:last-child>span {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="pipeline-box"><span>New</span></li>
  <li class="pipeline-box"><span>Order Placed</span></li>
  <li class="pipeline-box"><span>Order confirmed</span></li>
  <li class="pipeline-box"><span>In Process</span></li>
  <li class="pipeline-box"><span>Ready For Dispatch</span></li>
  <li class="pipeline-box"><span>On the Way</span></li>
  <li class="pipeline-box"><span>Delivered</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.

the HTML page is now

```
<ul class="pipeline-box">
    <li><span>New</span></li>
    <li><span>Order Placed</span></li>
    <li><span>Order confirmed</span></li>
    <li><span>In Process</span></li>
    <li><span>Ready For Dispatch</span></li>
    <li><span>On the Way</span></li>
    <li><span>Delivered</span></li>
</ul>
```

and the SCSS is

```
.pipeline-box {
      li{
        align-content: center;
        border: 1px solid #696666;
        text-align: center;
        width: 125px;
        padding: 6px;
        background: #f8f8f8;
        border-radius: 50px;
        font-family: "avenir Medium";
        font-size: 0.8rem !important;
        position: relative;
      }
      li:after{
        content: '';
        width: 17px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #afa4a4;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
        top: calc(50% - 2px);
        right: -18px;
      }
      li:before{
        content: '';
        width: 17px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #afa4a4;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
        top: calc(50% - 2px);
        left: -18px;

      }

      li:last-child:after {
        display: none;
      }

      li:first-child::before {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

It looks like this now.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxV4O.png)